# How to secure Node.js connect-rest REST API with OAuth?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, oauth, passport.js

I tried Googling around for some examples, or well anything, but couldn't find any results.  I think partially because the name of the package "connect-rest" is so generic.

Anyway, here is what i'm looking to do.  I am using the Node module "connect-rest" to build a server side API.  It is mostly finished at this point, and i'm now looking to secure it.  Now the module itself has a system of authentication with API Keys, which is well and fine, but not very secure for Javascript clients, since anyone could just browse the source and grab the key.  And trying to secure a key -- well it just doesn't work without getting super complicated.

So instead i'd rather use a standard OAuth setup.  I was hoping to use Passport in combination with connect-rest and wondering if anyone has done this before or point me to some examples?

Comment: OAuth is a front-end only thing, so asking for back-end code for it deosn't make much sense.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense?  The back-end API has to properly authenticate each request and i'm looking for some example of how to achieve that, preferably with Passport.  But i'll admit this is a shaky area for me so I might be misunderstanding it all.

Comment: all OAuth needs in terms of a back-end is some static text files at a url; something Apache alone can do without php...

Answer (score 0):

I found exactly what I needed with OAuthorize: https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauthorize which is written by the same guy as Passport.

Answer (score 0):

We used the following guide for our own learning when we started a similar process: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Also take a look at MeanJS. It has a built in authentication/user system.